# Python: Accessing HTTPS url over Proxy using Requests

Tags: python-2.7, https, python-requests

```
import shutil
import requests
import json

proxy = {
'user' : 'user',
'pass' : 'password',
'host' : "test.net",
'port' : 8080
}

url = 'https://github.com/timeline.json'
response = requests.get(url,verify=True, proxies={"https" : \
"http://%(user)s:%(pass)s@%(host)s:%(port)d" % proxy})

with open(r'..\test.json','wb') as out_file:
      out_file.write(response.text)
print response
```

I'm trying to access a HTTPS link (e.g https://github.com/timeline.json) over proxy in office environment using Requests.

Accessing HTTP link seems to be working fine. Getting SSL error in HTTPS. 
Please suggest what's missing in the code. Thanks!

Error received:

```
raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  For instance, including the full error message you are receiving would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure port 8080 is the right port? 443 is default https port, and 8080 is generally used as an alternative http port

Comment: I'm trying to access url like https://rhapsody.us-prod.net:443/test_link
which returns json data.

HTTP links are working just fine with the above proxy settings. Can you suggest the proxy settings to be used from the above rhapsody URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using almost the same code you provided, and searched an proxy server. Everything is OK with me.

Try to take a look at document [here requests proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies). And notice that https://github.com/timeline.json is deprecated by Github，try https://api.github.com/events

According to doc:
To use HTTP Basic Auth with your proxy, use the http://user:password@host/ syntax:

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/",
}
```

Are you missing a `/` at the end? Take a try.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/events'
proxy = {
        "http" : "http://211.162.xxx.xxx:80"
        }
response = requests.get(url, verify=True, proxies=proxy)
print response.status_code
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    jsontxt = response.json()
    print jsontxt
```

Comment: actually you didn't hit https url, because you didn't provide proxy for https protocol. reason that all worked OK for you - because you connected directly.